# PyQt4 label crashes when a function is called instead of using raw_input?

Tags: python-2.7, function, pyqt, pyqt4

I boiled the original code down to a small section that still reproduces the issue. The below code works fine with `action = raw_input('next action? ')` instead of `action = self.fake()`. WHY??!! Specifically, the 'label' window will hang and crash using the class function, but will display the two overlaid images no problem using the user input. I cannot fathom how the two are impacting PyQt, especially since the changes are being made AFTER the image update.

```
import time
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Basement(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel()

    def update_image(self):
        self.im = QtGui.QImage('n-wall.png')
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        c_image = QtGui.QImage('bed.png')
        painter.begin(self.im)
        painter.drawImage(10, 10, c_image)
        painter.end()
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.im))
        self.label.show()

    def fake(self):
        return 'left'


    def play_game(self):

        ### Update graphics / text
        self.update_image()

        ### Decide action
        action = self.fake()
        #action = raw_input('next action? ')

        time.sleep(5)


B = Basement()
B.play_game()
```

Comment: Every GUI is executed on an infinite loop, and this is used to check the signals, slots, events, etc. And if you create another loop that takes a long time you will block that task. The problem with the input () is that it behaves as a blocking agent causing inappropriate behavior. A solution although not very good for this case is to use threads to obtain data, the other correct solution is to use the input elements of the GUI such as QLineEdit, QTextEdit, etc.

Comment: In addition, in a GUI you must use the paradigm of object-oriented programming and event-oriented programming. In a GUI you should not use input (), raw_input (), etc but the elements of the GUI such as QLineEdit, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QCheckBox, QComboBox, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much for the insight!

Comment: I think I'd like to proceed with threading if it's not too complicated, do you know of any good simple examples that use threading?